# Problem with remember me button on mobile devices

Tags: php, authentication, cookies

I have made easy login system according to one article on web. If I click remember me button it stores these data (member_login, random_password, random_selector) in cookies on device, where I am logged in. First I used it just on PC.

Later I added IP address verificaction step to enable login on more devíces in same time due to I want to use my app also on mobile device.

Login system is working correctly on PC - there I can be logged in one month if I choose remember me during login.

On mobile devices, on every browser it randomly log out me after some random period.

**I already checked if cookies are created on mobile and it is ok.**

I could not find rootcause why. Can you please advice me what to check.

Here is my login code, where cookies are setted up:

```
<?php
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/_inc/functions.php');
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/_inc/auth/Util.php');
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/_inc/auth/Auth.php');

$auth = new Auth();
$db_handle = new DBController();
$util = new Util();

// Get Current date, time
$current_time = time();
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $current_time);

// Set Cookie expiration for 1 month (seconds from 1970 until current date + 1 month)
$cookie_expiration_time = $current_time + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60);  // for 1 month

// Auth.php chcek if user is loggedin
if ($_SESSION["user_id"]) {
    redirect_page("index.php");
    exit;
}

// check if login form was submitted
if (! empty($_POST['login'])) {

  $isAuthenticated = false;

  // get username and password from form
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  // get user from db
  $user = $auth->getMemberByUsername($username);

  // verify entered password with hashed password in db for user got above
  if (password_verify($password, $user[0]["password"])) {
      $isAuthenticated = true; // password is verified, next rocess of login can start
  }

  // if user is authenticated start to create cookies
  if ($isAuthenticated) {
      $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user[0]["id"];

      // Set Auth Cookies if 'Remember Me' checked
      if (! empty($_POST["remember"])) {

          $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

          // setcookie(string $name, string $value = "", int $expires = 0,)
          setcookie("member_login", $username, $cookie_expiration_time, '/'); // '/' cookies are available on each page

          $random_password = $util->getToken(16); // create token for cookie identification with db
          setcookie("random_password", $random_password, $cookie_expiration_time, '/'); // '/' cookies are available on each page

          $random_selector = $util->getToken(32);
          setcookie("random_selector", $random_selector, $cookie_expiration_time, '/'); // '/' cookies are available on each page

          // hash password and selector before inserting to db
          $random_password_hash = password_hash($random_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
          $random_selector_hash = password_hash($random_selector, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

          $expiry_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $cookie_expiration_time);

          // mark existing token as expired if new login
          $userToken = $auth->getTokenByUsername($username, 0);
          /*
          if (! empty($userToken[0]["id"])) {
              $auth->markAsExpired($userToken[0]["id"]);
          }
          */
          // Insert new token
          $auth->insertToken($username, $ip_address, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date);

      } else {
          $util->clearAuthCookie();
      }

      redirect_page("index.php");
      exit;

    } else {
        $_SESSION['login_error'] = 'Invalid password or username';
        redirect_page("back");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Hrere is my validation code to check cookies on each page:

```
<?php

/* FLow:
-> index -> header -> validatecookies ()
            -> continue index (logedin = true)
            -> redirect login
 */

require 'Util.php';
require 'Auth.php';

// create objects
$auth = new Auth();
$db_handle = new DBController();
$util = new Util();

$isLoggedIn = false;

// Check if loggedin session and redirect if session exists
if (! empty($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    $isLoggedIn = true;
}
// Check if loggedin cookies exists
else if (! empty($_COOKIE["member_login"]) && ! empty($_COOKIE["random_password"]) && ! empty($_COOKIE["random_selector"])) {
    // Initiate auth token verification directive to false
    $isPasswordVerified = false;
    $isSelectorVerified = false;
    $isExpiryDateVerified = false;

    // Get token for username from db
    $userToken = $auth->getTokenByIPaddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],0);
    // $userToken = $auth->getTokenByUsername($_COOKIE["member_login"],0);

    if ($userToken) {
    // check just in case of the same IP address

        // dual control via selector and password due to time leake secure issue (if just one token than according to response time from db it is possible to guess password easier)

        // Validate random password cookie with database
        if (password_verify($_COOKIE["random_password"], $userToken[0]["password_hash"])) {
            $isPasswordVerified = true;
        }

        // Validate random selector cookie with database
        if (password_verify($_COOKIE["random_selector"], $userToken[0]["selector_hash"])) {
            $isSelectorVerified = true;
        }

        // check cookie expiration by date
        if( ($userToken[0]["expiry_date"] >= $current_date) & ($userToken[0]["is_expired"] != 1) )  {
            $isExpiryDateVerified = true;
        }
    }
    // Redirect if all cookie based validation returns true
    // Else, mark the token as expired and clear cookies
    if (!empty($userToken[0]["id"]) && $isPasswordVerified && $isSelectorVerified && $isExpiryDateVerified) {
       $isLoggedIn = true;

    } else {

        if(!empty($userToken[0]["id"])) {
            $auth->markAsExpired($userToken[0]["id"]);
        }
        // clear cookies
        $util->clearAuthCookie();
        header ("Location: login.php");
        exit;
    }

} else {
// is no session and no cookies exist, just redirect on login

    header ("Location: login.php");

    exit;
}

?>
``
```

Comment: And the REMOTE_ADDR also stays the same, when you test this via your mobile?

Comment: REMOTE_ADDR is different if I use mobile device.

Comment: I found that it switches me everytime to some kind of insight mode on chrome and then it log out me.  Is there some way how to overcome it or just change settings of browser?